# Get XY coordinates from GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT() output

Tags: sql, oracle, geometry, coordinates, oracle-spatial

*Oracle 18c:*

How can I get the X & Y coordinates  from `GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT()`'s resulting LRS point?

```
select
  sdo_lrs.geom_segment_start_pt(sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)'))
from
  dual

SDO_LRS.GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT(SDO_GEOMETRY('LINESTRING(12,34,56)')) 
---------------------------------------------------
SDO_GEOMETRY(2001, NULL, NULL, SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1, 1, 1), SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY(1,2))
```

Note: The coordinates are stored in the SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY( ), not the SDO_POINT.

Desired output:

```
 X  Y
-- --
 1  2
```

Normally, I'd use something like `a.shape.sdo_point.x`. But I don't think that applies here  since the coordinates aren't stored in the SDO_POINT.

Related: Oracle Spatial Community - [Get X & Y coordinates from GEOM_SEGMENT_START_PT()](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/4499536/get-x-y-coordinates-from-geom-segment-start-pt/p1?new=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below SQL for getting X and Y coordinates

```
    select 
      t.X, 
      t.Y 
    from 
      TABLE(
        SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES(
          sdo_lrs.geom_segment_start_pt(
            sdo_geometry('linestring(1 2, 3 4, 5 6)')
          )
        )
      ) t;
```

Comment: I hope my answer answers your question

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Psaraj12's answer — using multiple rows as an example and removing `geom_segment_start_pt()`:

```
with cte as (
select sdo_geometry ('linestring (1 2, 3 4)', 26917) shape from dual union all
select sdo_geometry ('linestring (5 6, 7 8)', 26917) shape from dual union all
select sdo_geometry ('linestring (9 10, 11 12)', 26917) shape from dual)

select 
    * 
from 
    cte
cross join
    sdo_util.getvertices(cte.shape)
where
    id = 1
```

[image: strong text]

And I suppose I could get the **end**point by doing the same thing, but use this WHERE clause instead:

```
ID = SDO_UTIL.GETNUMVERTICES(SHAPE)
```

---

Related:

- [Cross-joining with a table object propagates rows (without needing Table() function)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590279/cross-joining-with-a-table-object-propagates-rows-without-needing-table-funct)
- [At what version did the TABLE() keyword for table collection expressions become optional?]](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499629/at-what-version-did-the-table-keyword-for-table-collection-expressions-become-optional)
- [Cross join to varray without using Table() expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595982/cross-join-to-varray-without-using-table-expression)

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option:

```
with data as (select sdo_geometry('linestring(10 20, 30 40, 50 60)') as shape from dual)

select 
    json_value((shape).Get_GeoJson(),'$.coordinates[0][0]') as startpoint_x
from 
    data
```

Source:

[Idea: Add a SDO_ORDINATES member function (for extracting collection elements by index)](https://community.oracle.com/tech/apps-infra/discussion/comment/16840191/#Comment_16840191)