# Cross-joining with a table object propagates rows (without needing Table() function)

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle18c, oracle-spatial, object-type

Oracle Spatial has a function called [SDO_UTIL.GETVERTICES](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/spatl/SDO_UTIL-reference.html#GUID-9CF1E8A9-EBCB-4938-BBB6-C2AAFE4897A7):

> This function returns an object of MDSYS.VERTEX_SET_TYPE, which
> consists of a **table** of objects of MDSYS.VERTEX_TYPE.
>
> ```
> CREATE TYPE vertex_set_type as TABLE OF vertex_type;
> ```

The `GetVertices()` function is typically used in conjunction with the `Table()` function. The geometry table is cross-joined with `table(getvertices(shape))` to propagate vertex rows for each geometry:

```
with cte as (
select sdo_geometry('linestring (10 20, 30 40)')                       shape from dual union all
select sdo_geometry('linestring (50 60, 70 80, 90 100)')               shape from dual union all
select sdo_geometry('linestring (110 120, 130 140, 150 160, 170 180)') shape from dual)
  
select 
    v.*
from 
    cte, table(sdo_util.getvertices(shape)) v

    X     Y     Z     W    V5    V6    V7    V8    V9   V10   V11    ID
----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
   10    20                                                           1
   30    40                                                           2
   50    60                                                           1
   70    80                                                           2
   90   100                                                           3
  110   120                                                           1
  130   140                                                           2
  150   160                                                           3
  170   180                                                           4
```

And the examples in the docs suggest using `Table()` as well.

But from a quick test, using the `table()` function doesn't seem to be necessary. If I remove the `Table()` function from the query, it produces the same result.

---

Question:

How is it possible that cross-joining with a table object propagates rows — without needing the `Table()` function?

The docs suggest that we *should* use the `Table()` function, so I wonder if that was correct in older versions of Oracle, but maybe something changed in newer versions?

---

Related:

- [At what version did the TABLE() keyword for table collection expressions become optional?](https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4499629/at-what-version-did-the-table-keyword-for-table-collection-expressions-become-optional)
- [Cross join to varray without using Table() expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72595982/cross-join-to-varray-without-using-table-expression)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How is it possible that cross-joining with a table object propagates rows — without needing the `Table()` function?

In either Oracle 12 or Oracle 18, the `TABLE` keyword for table collection expressions was made an optional part of the syntax so:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   TABLE(SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c'));
```

Will work on all oracle versions (that support collections).

And:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST('a', 'b', 'c');
```

Will work from Oracle 18 (and maybe Oracle 12) and do exactly the same thing (but would raise syntax errors in earlier versions).

---

I'm trying to find the documentation for the new feature but so far haven't found it.

Comment: @User1974 Its not obviously listed in the [Oracle 12.2 new features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/newft/new-features.html) or in the [Oracle 18 new features](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/newft/new-features.html) and it isn't in the [Oracle 18 `SELECT` syntax diagram](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6). It looks to be an undocumented (or a very poorly documented) feature that was introduced.