# Cross join to varray without using Table() expression

Tags: sql, oracle, join, oracle18c

I'm trying to learn about cross joining to varray collections.

---

**Example 1:** The following query works. It propagates rows via cross joining to the elements in the varray column `letter_array`, using the `Table()` expression:

```
with cte as (
select 1 as id, sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b')           as letter_array from dual union all
select 2 as id, sys.odcivarchar2list('c', 'd', 'e', 'f') as letter_array from dual)

select 
    cte.id,
    t.column_value
from 
    cte
cross join
    table(letter_array) t

   ID   COLUMN_VALUE
-----   -----------
    1   a    
    1   b    

    2   c    
    2   d    
    2   e    
    2   f
```

It produces *n* rows for each `ID` (*n* is a varying number of elements in the `letter_array`).

---

**Example 2:** In a related post, we determined that the [`TABLE()` keyword for collections is now ***optional***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72590279/cross-joining-with-table-object-propagates-rows-without-needing-table-functio).

So, in the next example (with slightly different data), I'll use `sys.odcivarchar2list('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')` hardcoded in the join, without using the `TABLE()` expression:

```
with cte as (
select 1 as id from dual union all
select 2 as id from dual)

select 
    *
from 
    cte
cross join
    sys.odcivarchar2list('c', 'd', 'e', 'f')

   ID   COLUMN_VALUE
-----   ------------
    1   c    
    1   d    
    1   e    
    1   f    

    2   c    
    2   d    
    2   e    
    2   f
```

That works as expected too. It produces 4 rows for each ID (4 is the number of elements in the hardcoded varray expression).

---

**Example 3:** However, what I actually want, is to use the data from the first example, except this time, use a varray **column** in the join, **without using the `TABLE()` expression:**

```
with cte as (
select 1 as id, sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b')           as letter_array from dual union all
select 2 as id, sys.odcivarchar2list('c', 'd', 'e', 'f') as letter_array from dual)

select 
    cte.id,
    t.column_value
from 
    cte
cross join
    letter_array t
```

Error:

```
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 11 Column: 10
```

---

**Question:**

How can I cross join to the varray without using the Table() expression?

Comment: letter_array could only be a part of the cte, so it can't be a function like sys.odcivarchar2list with which you can omit the table(), you trying something impossisslbe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CROSS APPLY`:

```sql
with cte (id, letter_array) as (
  select 1, sys.odcivarchar2list('a', 'b')           from dual union all
  select 2, sys.odcivarchar2list('c', 'd', 'e', 'f') from dual
)
select id,
       t.column_value
from   cte
       CROSS APPLY letter_array t
```

Which outputs:

> | ID | COLUMN_VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | a |
> | 1 | b |
> | 2 | c |
> | 2 | d |
> | 2 | e |
> | 2 | f |

---

*Note: Using a legacy comma join, ANSI `CROSS JOIN` and `CROSS JOIN LATERAL` all fail, in Oracle 18c and 21c, without the `TABLE` keyword and succeed with it. See the fiddle below.*

*Note 2: `TABLE(...)` is not a function, it is the [syntax for a table collection expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) (which wraps a collection expression).*

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1e0632987b3a265d61371384f2ea1b7e)*

Comment: @User1974 From [the `SELECT` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6) "The *table_collection_expression* lets you inform Oracle that the value of *collection_expression* should be treated as a table for purposes of query and DML operations." So its not a "table collection" expression it is a table from a "collection expression" and a collection can be either a nested table, VARRAY or an associative array (although, in this case, it cannot be an associative array as that's generally PL/SQL only).